# If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Continuing my work through Dummit & Foote's "Abstract Algebra", 3.1.36 asks the following (which is exactly the same as exercise 5 in [this related MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44995/are-cyclic-groups-always-abelian-commutative/45042#45042)):

> Prove that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. [If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic with generator $xZ(G)$, show that every element of $G$ can be written in the form $x^az$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and some element $z \in Z(G)$]

The hint is actually the hardest part for me, as the quotient groups are somewhat abstract. But once I have the hint, I can write:

$g, h \in G$ implies that $g = x^{a_1}z_1$ and $h = x^{a_2}z_2$, so
\begin{align*}gh &= (x^{a_1}z_1)(x^{a_2}z_2)\\\
 &= x^{a_1}x^{a_2}z_1z_2\\\
& = x^{a_1 + a_2}z_2z_1\\\
&= \ldots = (x^{a_2}z_2)(x^{a_1}z_1) = hg.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $G$ is abelian. 
1) Is this right so far? 
2) How can I prove the "hint"?

Comment: That is correct. To prove the hint, just think that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then we can write $G/Z(G)=\langle xZ(G)\rangle$ for some $x\in G$. This means that for every $g\in G$, $gZ(G)=x^mZ(G)$ for some $m$, and thus $x^{-m}g\in Z(G)$. Do you see how to finish the proof?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I think so. Where did the negative exponent come from? Would you want to make this comment a formal "answer"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof that if group $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is commutative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/proof-that-if-group-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-commutative)

Comment: While this result isn't hard to prove and makes a decent bit of intuitive sense, it has always struck me as a strange statement.

Comment: @Sean, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point

Answer (score 108, accepted):

We have that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, and so there is an element $x\in G$ such that $G/Z(G)=\langle xZ(G)\rangle$, where $xZ(G)$ is the coset with representative $x$. Now let $g\in G$.

We know that $gZ(G)=(xZ(G))^m$ for some $m$, and by definition $(xZ(G))^m=x^mZ(G)$.

Now, in general, if $H\leq G$, we have by definition too that $aH=bH$ if and only if $b^{-1}a\in H$.

In our case, we have that $gZ(G)=x^mZ(G)$, and this happens if and only if $(x^m)^{-1}g\in Z(G)$.

Then, there's a $z\in Z(G)$ such that $(x^{m})^{-1}g=z$, and so $g=x^mz$.

The hint is then proved, and the rest is identical to the work you did.

Comment: Many thanks! That was easy to follow.

Comment: @Robert: I am extremely confused about one thing. A group is abelian if and only its its center is the whole group. Then isn't $G/Z(G)$ the trivial group in this case?

Comment: Yes, the proof shows then that $G/Z(G)$ is actually trivial.

Comment: Why "by defintion $(xZ(G))^m=x^mZ(G)$? That should be proven it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Dear Twink, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and $x,y\in G$, then by definition $(xH)(yH)=xyH$.

Comment: if this result holds i.e.,$G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian $then$ $G=Z(G) \implies \vert G/Z(G) \vert =1$.Hence, in this case $G/Z(G) $ is a trivial group.

Answer (score 8):

The following is another way to show the hint:

We know that the left cosets of $Z(G)$ partition the group $G$. So for all $g\in G$ there exists $n\in N, \ z\in Z(G)$ such that $x^nz=g$, where $xZ(G)$ generates $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: Follow up question. Should this be an if and only if statement? For if $G$ is abelian, then $Z(G) = G$. So $G/G \simeq {0}$. The 0 group is trivially cyclic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another proof of the fact that, if $G/\textbf{Z}(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian:

Since $G/\textbf{Z}(G)\cong \text{Inn}(G)$, then $\text{Inn}(G)$ is cyclic. So there exists some $g\in G$ such that every conjugation in $G$ is a product of conjugations of $g$. Now, let $x,y\in G$. We can write $$[x,y]=x^{-1}x^y=x^{-1}x^{g^k},$$
for some integer $k$. So it suffices to show that $x$ and $g$ conmute. But this is clear, since $$[g,x]=g^{-1}g^x=g^{-1}g^{g^l}=1,$$
for some $l\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof of the following statement:

Let $G$ be a group, $N\leq G$ a subgroup of $G$.  If $N\leq Z(G)$ and $G/N$ is cyclic then $G=Z(G)$.

---

Let $gN$ be a generator of $G/N$.  Since $N\leq Z(G)$ clearly $N\subseteq C_{G}(g)$.  By definition, $g\in C_{G}(g)$ as well.  Hence $C_{G}(g)/N = G/N$.  From the correspondance theorem it follows that $C_{G}(g) = G$, and hence $g\in Z(G)$.  So again $Z(G)/N = G/N$ and therefore by the correspondance theorem again $Z(G) = G$.