# A question about cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. If G contains a normal subgroup $H$ of order 2, show that $G$ is cyclic.

I was thinking to find a element and prove that it is the generator of $G$, but I cannot find that. could somebody give be some hints.

Comment: If $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $2$, what does that tell you about the centre of $G$?

Comment: $H$ is in the centre of $G$

Comment: Right. So what are the possibilities for $G/Z(G)$?

Comment: What is $G/H$? Since $H \subset Z(G)$, $G/Z(G)$ must be a quotient of that.

Comment: You mean there are $p$ elements in $G/H$? Is that right? Actually I don't know why the order of $G/H$ is $p$, I am not sure about that even.

Comment: For $G/H$ order check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29

Comment: @user121819: yes, if $\# G = 2p$ and $\# H = 2$, then $\# G/H = p$.  You say you are unsure about this.  Why?  Do you know Lagrange's Theorem?

Answer (score 5):

Daniel Fischer has done a nice job giving helpful hints rather than a complete answer.  I just wanted to mention that I think that the solution that he is nudging the OP towards uses [this standard, elementary fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian).

Comment: could you write a detailed answer, I just want to make sure I think it through

Comment: @user121819: Well, what have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 0):

One direction would be to use the fact that there is ([Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)) an element of order $p$ in $G$. The cyclic (order $p$) subgroup generated by it, call it $K$, is normal (has index 2). Then we can note that the two subgroups intersection is null and $G$ is generated by the their generators. If the two generators commute (they do, due to the normality of $H$), then $G$ is abelian, hence cyclic (order of the product of the two generators is $2p$).

See also the comments above (and the answer linked to them, posted above) and very explicit approach at http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/groups-of-order-2p/

Comment: Sorry, we have not learnt about Sylow's theorems so I really don't understand what's $K$ like. Could you explain it?

Comment: Sylow's theorem seems unnecessary to bring up, really.

Comment: I agree. We just need to show that $K$, subgroup of order $p$, exists.

Comment: @user121819 this http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/groups-of-order-2p/ seems to give an explicit (and better) proof.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff I "fixed" it, I think. Best regards.