# Permutation representation: why is G isomorphic to a subgroup of the normalizer of $(1\:\ldots\:q)$ in $S_q$?

Tags: group-theory

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962956/prove-that-a-non-abelian-group-of-order-pq-pq-has-a-nonnormal-subgroup-of%20%22This%20question) appears in Dummit and Foote, which I am self-studying.  It asks the student to show that, given a non-abelian group $G$ with $|G| = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime and $p < q$, there exists a nonnormal subgroup $H \leq G$ with $|G:H| = q$, and that this guarantees the existence of an injective homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_q$ (i.e., the permutation representation associated with the action of left multiplying left cosets of $H$ by elements of $G$).  I have managed to accomplish this, albeit with a slightly different argument than the one given in the linked question.

There is, however, a final part to the question: we are asked to deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the normalizer of $(1\:\ldots\:q)$ in $S_q$.  Here I am stuck, which leads me to believe that there is something I am failing to understand about permutation representations generally.

We certainly know that $G$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_q$, as $\ker \phi = 1$ and left multiplication by $G$ is permuting $q$ elements; we further know that this action is transitive--that is, given any two left cosets $aH, bH$ of $H$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $g\cdot aH = bH$. But I do not understand where the cycle $(1\:\ldots\:q)$ enters the picture; I therefore do not understand why its normalizer makes an appearance.  I'm not sure I need a complete solution--I'm more interested in a gentle nudge toward understanding the situation, so that I can work out the details myself.

Comment: You mean $|G|=pq$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I do/did.  Corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an embedding $G\to S_q$, so you may consider $G$ to **be** a subgroup
of $S_q$. Your group $G$ contains a normal subgroup $K$ of order $q$,
and this is generated by an element of order $q$ in $S_q$, $\sigma $ say.
Then $\sigma$ is a cycle of length $q$ (since these are the only order
$q$ elements in $S_q$). All $q$-cycles are conjugate in $S_q$. Thus by replacing
$G$ by a conjugate subgroup one may assume that $\sigma$ is your favourite
$q$-cycle $(1\,2\,\cdots\,q)$. Then $K=\left<\sigma\right>$. But $K$
is normal in $G$; therefore $G$ is contained in the normaliser of $K$
within $S_q$.