# If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian – what is the point?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

The theorem "if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian" is a popular exercise.

But what is the point of this theorem if $G/Z(G)$ can only be cyclic if it is trivial?

Does "$G/Z(G)$ is cyclic" actually appears in other proofs or is it just a popular exercise?

Comment: Yes, it comes up in Sylow theory.  I cannot recall the theorem off the top of my head...

Comment: Well, for instance the theorem implies that $G/Z(G)$ cannot have prime order.  That's useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This other question is using the fact that $G/Z(G)$ being cyclic implies that $G$ is abelian to show that non abelian groups of order $pq$ have a trivial center [Verification of Proof that a nonabelian group G of order pq where p and q are primes has a trivial center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999260/verification-of-proof-that-a-nonabelian-group-g-of-order-pq-where-p-and-q-are-pr)

Comment: Good one, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

A nice application is in proving that the center of a  non-abelian cannot be too large:

> If $G$ is a non-abelian finite group, then $|Z(G)| \leq \frac {1}{4} |G|$.

The contrapositive is

> If $|Z(G)| > \frac {1}{4} |G|$, then $G$ is abelian.

Indeed, $|Z(G)| > \frac {1}{4} |G|$ implies that $G/Z(G)$ has order at most $3$, and so is cyclic.

Comment: An application of your application is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211159/why-cant-a-nonabelian-group-be-75-abelian

Answer (score 7):

Say you want to prove the following.

Every group $G$ of order $p^2$ ($p$ is a prime) is abelian.

You can apply this result.

Since $G$ is a $p$-group, it has a non trivial center $Z(G)$.

Therefore $|G/Z(G)|=1$ or $p$.

Therefore $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and $G$ is abelian.

There are many other applications.

Comment: It still leaves a bad taste because the cases $|Z(G)|=1$ or $p$ never happens. I never really liked proofs by contradiction of the form: To prove $P$, assume not $P$, deduce $P$, and call it a contradiction.

Comment: It does perturb me too. "Let us assume $Z(G)\neq G$. Hence $Z(G)=G$. Contradiction!" Kind of mysterious.

Comment: How is this a proof by contradiction in any manner?

Comment: @MikeMiller We assume $Z(G)\neq G$ and arrive at a contradiction. That is a proof by contradiction. I don't see my mistake.

Comment: You never assumed $Z(G) \neq G$. The proof you have in your own answer is perfectly direct.

Comment: @ihf I am glad I found your comment because tis confused the crap out of me when I read proofs like that.