# Given $|G|=pq$, $p \leq q$ and $p,q$ prime. If $Z(G)=1$ and all non-identity have order $p$ then the centralizer of every group element has order $p$.

Tags: group-theory

Assertion from Dummit and Foote 3rd p136: Given a group $G$ of order $pq$, $p \leq q$ and $p,q$ are prime. If $Z(G)=1$ and all non-identity has order $p$ then the centralizer of every group element has order $p$.

I can't follow the argument: I understand that centralizer must have order $p$ or $q$ but why it cannot have $q$ elements here. It doesn't look very obvious to me.

Comment: What is the order of a non-identity element in a (sub)group of order $q$?

Comment: oh I see... thank you

Comment: Aside: $G$ has trivial center here iff $G$ is non-abelian: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999260/verification-of-proof-that-a-nonabelian-group-g-of-order-pq-where-p-and-q-are-pr.