# Group of order 27 could be non abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How do you prove a group of order 27 can be non abelian?

From what I tried:

Say $|G|=27$ then it's a p-group therefore the ceneter is non trivial so $|Z(G)|$ could be either $3,9,27$ if $|Z(G)|=27$ then the group is abelian. if $|Z(G)|=9$ then from lagrange $|G/Z(G)|=3$ therefore cyclic therefore $G$ is abelian (which is very strange to me although I'm using the theorems I just found an abelian group $G\neq Z(G)$). and if $Z(G)=3$ then I know that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian because it's of order 9 but I don't know how to continue from here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may enjoy http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point

Comment: Arguing in generalities is the wrong thing to do. It's pointless. It's like saying "There can be a prime between $n$ and $2n$ for $n>1$ because  $2n-n>1$." That proves that there's an integer in that range, which could be prime, but it doesn't prove there's a prime, and not every integer in the range is prime.

Answer (score 6):

You should prove by **giving an example** since not every group of order $27$ are non-abelian.

Take $$G=\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;|\; a,b,c\in \Bbb{Z}_3\}$$
Try to verify that this group is a non-abelian group of order $27$.
In fact it is called the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.
It is subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb{Z}_3$)

Comment: Thank you this will definitely work but I'm looking for a constructive answer. I would use the argument that if $|G| \neq |Z(G)|$ then the group is not abelian but for some reason if $|G|\neq |Z(G)|=9$ this results that G is abelian so I cannot use this argument if $|Z(G)|=3$ do you understand my confusion?

Comment: @KimSeel In fact for every nonabelian group of order $p^3$, $|Z(G)|=p$, $Z(G)=G'$ and $G/Z(G)\cong \Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$. Do you mean you want to construct a nonabelian group of order $27$ using these informations?

Comment: I know if the group is non-abelian of order $p^3$ then what you said follows. but if all the information I have is the the group is of order $p^3$,$|Z(G)|=3$, then how do I prove the group is non abelian?

Comment: @KimSeel A group $G$ is abelian iff $G=Z(G)$. If $|Z(G)|=3$, clearly $G\neq Z(G)$, hence $G$ is nonabelian.

Comment: @AlanWang 's solution to the question you pose is perfect.

Comment: I agree with the theorem that $G$ is abelian iff $G=Z(G)$ but then what's wrong with my proof that when I assumed $|Z(G)|=9$ and I proved that G is abelian?

Comment: Finally I know what you are confused with. Suppose $|Z(G)|=9$, $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and hence $G$ is abelian. Hence $G=Z(G)$; a contradiction. This means that **"$|Z(G)|=9$" can never be happened.**

Comment: Ok, how can I be sure there's no contradiction with $|Z(G)|=3$ and thus G must be abelian?

Comment: @KimSeel I can't understand what you mean.