# Group of order $p^2$ with Center of order $p$

Tags: group-theory

I am sure this question was asked here before, maybe even multiple times. But I can't find it right now and it really bugs me:

> Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=p^2$. Then $G$ is abelian.

For the proof we have 3 cases: $|Z(G)|\in\{1,p,p^2\}$, two of which I understand. Let $|Z(G)|=p$, then $G/Z(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}_p$, so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclical and therefore $G$ is abelian.

Question: This would mean that $Z(G)=G$, so there it's ultimately a contradiction although it proofs that $G$ is abelian. How do I interpret this proof?

Comment: "But I can't find it right now" - I can't believe that you have searched; it comes up immediately, with multiple duplicates.

Comment: I have found the one linked above. But my question is not being answered there.

Comment: That argument shows $G$ does not have a center of order $p$. It does *not* prove $G$ is abelian. As you wrote, the argument leads to a contradiction. Do not be fooled because it involves a concision you want.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, $|Z(G)|=1,p  \text{ or } p^2$. If $|Z(G)|=p$, then by [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Order_Prime_Squared_is_Abelian) argument, $|G/Z(G)|=p$ which implies $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. But as the proof mentions, this cannot be the case because of [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_of_Group_by_Center_Cyclic_implies_Abelian) result. Hence $|Z(G)|=p^2=|G|$, so that $Z(G)=G$ and $G$ is abelian.