# $|G| \geq4 |Z(G)|$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G, \times)$ be a finite non abelian group and let $Z(G)$ be it center.

I would like to proove that : $| G | \geq 4 | Z(G) |$

I don't have the intuition of this result and 
I don't know how to prove this result but maybe I should use the following properties :

1. $Z(G)$ is a group
2. $| Z(G) |\mid |G|$
3. Cayley table

Comment: The smallest non-cyclic group has order 4.

Comment: Hint: Show that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then in fact $G=Z(G)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1466937/589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $Z(G)$ is a group and hence $|Z(G)|$ divides $|G|$ (by Lagrange) gets you halfway there:  $|Z(G)|$ can't be equal to $|G|$ since $G$ is non-Abelian so it must be at most half of $|G|$.

To get the other factor of two, we use the fact that $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$, so that their quotient group is well-defined.  Then we can be more refined in our use of Lagrange's theorem.

The order of $G / Z(G)$ is $\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}$, so if $|G| < 4|Z(G)|$ then Lagrange's theorem shows this quotient group has either $1,2$ or $3$ elements.  The first case contradicts the assumption that $G$ is non-Abelian.  The second two cases, being prime orders, imply that $G / Z(G)$ is cyclic.

But if that's the case, then there is some $g \in G$ such that $gZ(G)$ generates $G / Z(G)$.  Now pick an arbitrary $x \in G$. Since the cosets of $Z(G)$ partition $G$, we find $x$ in $g^k Z(G)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Of course it follows that $x$ itself is in the center of $G$.