# Find the order of $Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $G$ be a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime integers then find $|Z(G)|$. The options are i) 1 or $p$ ii) 1 or $q$ iii) 1 or $pq$ iv) None of these. I know groups of prime order are cyclic so $G$ will atleast have one subgroup of order $p$ or $q$. But how will I find out $|Z(G)|$ from this?

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ distinct?

Comment: @Stefan - That does not matter.

Comment: @NickyHekster: If $p=q$ the group is necessarily abelian and so $Z=G$. If $p\ne q$ then the group may be non abelian(dihedral).

Comment: @Shabab - yes exaclty so answer (iii) applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the result that *[if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian)*. This rules out $\lvert Z(G) \rvert=p$ or $q$. If $G$ is abelian, then $G=Z(G)$. Also, $\lvert Z(G) \rvert=1$ can be realized (an example is $G=S_3$, but can be generalized to $p$ or $q$ arbitrary, with $p \neq q$).

Comment: How do I know if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic or not? I could not understand why are you ruling out $|Z(G)| = p$ or $q$.

Comment: @In78 - $|Z(G)| \mid |G|$. So $|Z(G)| \in \{ 1, p, q, pq \}$. If $|Z(G)|=p$, then $|G/Z(G)|=q$, so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, whence $G$ is abelian and $G=Z(G)$, a contradiction. Same reasoning applies to the case $|Z(G)|=q$. Hope this clarifies it.