# Index of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if ***G*** is a finite group, the index of ***Z(G)*** cannot be prime.

What I have so far:

-Suppose ***G*** is Abelian, then ***G*** = ***Z(G)***. In this case the order of ***G:Z(G)*** would just be ***1*** which isn't prime.

What next?

Comment: Given the negative nature of what is to be proved, the only natural starting point would seem to be to suppose $G:Z(G)$ is a prime number, and try to derive a contradiction from this. What you have done (and any other special cases incompatible with $G:Z(G)$ being a prime number) is irrelevant for the proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you know that:

> If $G/Z(G)$ is a cyclic group then $G$ is abelian.

and every group with prime order is cyclic .

Comment: I did not know that.  How do you prove it?

Comment: you can for example see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian)

Comment: Interesting . . . thanks.

Answer (score 5):

suppose $x \notin Z(G)$, and let $C_x$ be the centralizer of $x$. clearly 
$$
Z(G) \subset C_x \subset G
$$
the first inclusion is proper, by construction, and the second cannot be, because $[G:Z(G)]$ is a prime. thus $C_x = G$,  contradicting the assumption that $x \notin Z(G)$

Comment: Sorry, why is it clear that Z(G) is a proper subset of $C_{x}$?

Comment: because the center of G is included in all centralizers of elements of G. but  also the centralizer of any element $x$ certainly includes $<x>$ - the subgroup generated by $x$.  since $x$ was assumed outside the center of G, ipso facto the centralizer of $x$ must contain at least one element $(x)$ not in the center of G

Answer (score 2):

Let $|G|=n< \infty$ and suppose $[G:Z(G)] = |G|/|Z(G)| = p\ $ where $p$ is prime. Then $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow$ cyclic $\Rightarrow G$ is abelian; hence $|Z(G)|=|G| \Rightarrow [G:Z(G)]=1$ which is not prime. Thus you have your claim.

Comment: It seems to me like this argument takes unnecessary detours in order to use the hypothesis that $G$ is finite (which isn't really necessary.)  For example, the fact that $[G : Z(G)] = |G|/|Z(G)|$ doesn't seem to get used.

Comment: This is why I don't get on math exchange often. No proof is perfect, if you have an alternative, just post it. I really don't care.

Comment: What is why?  Comments?

Comment: This is how I seen the proof. I don't care what you see as necessary and unnecessary, especially for a 2 line proof. Please I really don't want to say anymore.

Comment: Why is G/Z(G) isomorphic to Z/pZ?

Comment: @JeremyBaziw By First Isomorphism Theorem. Notice that Z(G) is normal.