# ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I would appreciate if you could please express your opinion about my proof. I'm not yet very good with automorphisms, so I'm trying to make sure my proofs are OK.

Proof:

Since ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is abelian. Thus for any elements $\phi, \psi \in{\rm Aut}(G)$ and some elements $g_i \in G$, $\phi\psi(g_1g_2)=\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=g_3g_4=\phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)=\phi\psi(g_2g_1)=g_4g_3$. Hence, $g_3g_4=g_4g_3\implies G$ is abelian.

The proof seems to be quite straightforward, but I'd rather ask for advice.

Comment: Ir cannot be right, there are non-Abelian groups with Abelian automorphism group. About the proof, I do not see a justification for the third equality.  Actually the proof does not even use the fact that $\phi$ and $\psi$ commute.

Comment: For clarity, I could write it this way:
$\phi\psi(g_1g_2)=\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=g_3g_4$

But $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2) = \phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)=g_4g_3$. Hence, $g_3g_4=g_4g_3\implies G$ is abelian.

Will this now make a proof?

Comment: Exactly the same comments continue to apply. You did not even use $\phi\psi=\psi\phi$. And anyway $\phi\psi=\psi\phi$ is not enough to prove the original group is Abelian.  One needs cyclic.

Comment: I'm not seeing why my argument, if it shows that $g_3g_4 = g_4g_3$, is not good.

Comment: But it does not show $g_3g_4=g_4g_3$. In the third equation it essentially asserts, with no justification, that they are equal.  What is written makes no progress towards a proof. Tweaking will not do it.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I believe there's something that is not clear still. By definition of a homomorphism, if $\phi\psi(g_1) = g_3$ and $\phi\psi(g_2) = g_4$, then $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2) = g_3 g_4$. But  since $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2) = \phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)$ and $\phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1) = g_4 g_3$ then the result follows. Please let me know why exactly this is not right.

Comment: What is not right is the assertion that $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=\phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)$.

Comment: If $Aut(G)$ is cyclic, then any element of it can be expressed as $\phi^k$ for some integer $k$. Now take $\phi^k(g_1g_2) = \phi^r\phi^s(g_1g_2) = \phi^r\phi^s(g_1)\phi^r\phi^s(g_2) = \phi^r\phi^s(g_2)\phi^r\phi^s(g_1)$. Why is this not correct?

Comment: There is the same unjustified interchange of order in the last equation.  As has been suggested in answers, work with the inner automorphisms of the original group.

Comment: Actually, we could use the property that because $Aut(G)$ is cyclic, $Aut(G)$ must be abelian. Thus for any $\phi \in Aut(G)$, $\phi(g_1g_2)=\phi(g_2g_1) = \phi(g_2)\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2) = g_3g_4=g_4g_3$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Much earlier I had mentioned that **there are** non-Abelian groups whose automorphism group is Abelian. So you will never be able to derive Abelianness of $G$ from the Abelianness of its automorphism group. The third equation is unjustified. Every one of your calculations has assumed $G$ is Abelian.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a nice chain of small results which proves this which continues down the path that Groups suggests.  If ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, then so is any subgroup of it, in particular ${\rm Inn}(G)$.  ${\rm Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$ where $Z(G)$ is the center.  If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, the group is abelian.

Comment: What says that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.  That's what I'm stuck on.

Comment: @DanielDonnelly https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian?noredirect=1&lq=1 has a nice solution to that part

Answer (score 9):

The $\phi,\psi$ commute, and also the following steps are also OK:
$$\phi\psi(g_1g_1)=\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=g_3g_4.$$
Its not clear in your argument why $g_3g_4=\phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)$?

We are allowed to use commutativity of *maps* $\phi,\psi$, and we have to *conclude* commutativity of $g_1,g_2$. You may proceed in following directions.

(1) Consider a specific subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, namely ${\rm Inn}(G)$. How it is related with $G$?

(2) ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, so is ${\rm Inn}(G)$, then using (1), what this will imply?

Comment: For clarity, I could write it this way:
$\phi\psi(g_1g_2)=\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=g_3g_4$

But $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2) = \phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)=g_4g_3$. Hence, $g_3g_4=g_4g_3\implies G$ is abelian.

Will this now make a proof?

Comment: why $\phi\psi(g_1)\phi\psi(g_2)=\phi\psi(g_2)\phi\psi(g_1)$? Here, LHS is product of two elements **in $G$**, and RHS is product of **same elements in reverse order**; we know **automorphisms** $\phi,\psi$ commute, but do not know at this stage how **elements of $G$**  namely $\phi\psi(g_1)$ and $\phi\psi(g_2)$ commute?