# Show that $G$ is abelian if $G$ is of order $42$ and $Z(G)$ has size $6$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Any help on how to prove the following:

> If a group $G$ is of order $42$ with center of size $6$, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: "need some help to prove that...." - so you tried it yourself and got stuck somewhere, right? Can you please elaborate and share your attempts?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $G/Z(G)$ is of order $7$ and thus cylic, so the statement follows from the fact that [$G$ is abelian if $G/Z(G)$ is cylic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian).

I think it is interesting to notice that formally speaking, this shows that no such group $G$ exists, because $G$ being abelian implies $Z(G) = G$, so $Z(G)$ is of order $42$ and not $6$. So the statement, that every such group $G$ is abelian, is true because not such group exists.

Comment: you've opened my mind to fact that the order of $G$ and $Z(G)$ are different Although $|G:Z(G)|=7$. Is that means that the question is wrong??

Comment: The statement of the question is right: Every group $G$ with $|G|=42$ and $|Z(G)| = 6$ is abelian. It is just that there exists no such group. So every statement about such a group $G$ is true. (I feel like this is more of a technicality then the indented answer to the question.)

Comment: so if such a group does not exist can we add any statement we want(for exp it is polycyclic)???

Comment: Yes, because for every group $G$ the implication "($|G| = 42$ and $|Z(G)| = 6$) $\implies$ statement" holds.

Comment: ok thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Examine the quotient $G/Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

First $Z(G)\trianglelefteq G$. Now consider $G/Z(G)$. We have that $|G/Z(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=\frac{42}{6}=7$.

Up to isomorphism, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is the only group of order $7$. So $G/Z(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_7$.

There is a lemma that says that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. The result follows from this lemma.