# Prove that G is abelian if (G:H) is prime, where H is in Z(G)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm attempting to prove this, but am quite frankly stuck and haven't made any progress.

I know that $\frac{|G|}{|H|}=p$, and I know by Cauchy's thm, that $\exists x \in G$ such that $x^p$ = e, and that any group of prime order is cyclic which implies Abelian, but that's as many relevant details I can think of. Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the duplicate and its not entirely helpful answer, it might be an idea to ask explicitly, "why can't $G/Z(G)$ be nontrivial and cyclic?" as a new question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That particular question would undoubtedly be rapidly closed as a duplicate to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63087/29335) or one of its numerous duplicates. I didn't grep through all of the dupes, but almost certainly one has pointed out that conclusion...

Comment: @rschwieb: Ah, that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

If the quotient group has prime order then it is cyclic. If the quotient group is cyclic then $G$ is Abelian.