# The order of the Center of the given Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Given that
> $$\displaystyle G=\{e,x,x^2,x^3,y,xy,x^2 y,x^3y \}$$ with ${\rm ord}(x)=4$ and ${\rm ord}(y)=2$ such that $xy=yx^3$
>
> Then find the number of elements in the center of the group $G$

**The solution I tried:**

Given group has order $8=2^3$ thus its the order of its center will be of form $2^n$ and also ${\rm ord}(Z(G))>1$

If the order of $Z(G)$ is $4$ then the quotient  ${\rm ord} \dfrac{G}{Z(G)}=2$ which is not possible, and the order $8$ is also not possible because $x$ doesn't commute with every element. So the order of $Z(G)$ will be  $2$, but my question is,  how can I use the given condition to prove this, what is the use of that condition given in question?

Please help.

Comment: You've shown something stronger, that every non-abelian group of order 8 has 2 elements in it's center. The condition is needed to verify that $G$ is in fact a group of order $8$ (i.e is closed and so every element can be written as $x^i y^j)$

Comment: so i have to use that condition to show that group is of order $8$?

Comment: I got it, given is that $xy=yx^3$ so multpilying both sides with $x$ we get $xyx=y$ thus it will become $xy=yx^{-1}$ which implies that $x$ and $y$ don not commute ,so order of center is less the $8$ am i right?

Comment: That's correct, but more work than you need. Notice that condition immediately implies $x$ and $y$ do not commute.

Comment: How do you deduce that the center is not trivial? How do you deduce that the quotient can't have size $2$?

Comment: If one is being very pedantic, one could say that it's not given that the order of the group is $8$, as some of the elements could be repeated. (For example, we could have $y=x^2$ and the order conditions would be met, but not the last one. One would then have to check to eliminate such things.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that means just looking at group (given above) i can't say that order of group is $8$ ,that means i have to use that given condition to find out the exact order of the group?

Comment: @Student I'm not implying anything like that.  The order of a group is how many elements a group has.  I'm actually asking: how did you come to the conclusion that the center has more than one element and that it can't have size $2$ before actually figuring out which elements form the center?

Comment: @Student I think you were trying to ask that to the other commenter

Comment: This is a Theorem that if order of group is of form $p^n$ then its center have order >1 ,and for second one i.e size of center is $2$ ,i apologise for that because i think that if  $ord (\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ =2 then by Theorem $G$ become cyclic ,but it is not given in question,but i assumed it is given that Group is not cyclic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identify that $|Z(G)|$ divides $|G|=8$ so $|Z(G)|\in\{1,2,4,8\}$

You correctly note that $|Z(G)|\ne 4$ so you need to show $|Z(G)|\ne 8$ (this follows immediately from the given conditions) and $|Z(G)|\ne 1$. For the latter, just find $1\ne z\in Z(G)$.

Comment: How does one quickly see that $|Z(G)| \neq 4$ and $|Z(G)| \neq 1$?

Comment: $|Z(G)|\ne 4$ because otherwise we'd have $G/Z(G)$ cyclic so $G$ abelian so $|Z(G)|=8$. For $|Z(G)|\ne 1$ check that $x^2\in Z(G)$

Comment: Why would the fact that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic be enough to deduce that $G$ is abelian? I agree that it's quick to check that $x^2 \in Z(G)$ since we have $\{x,y\}$ as our generating set.

Comment: Never mind, I found a [post about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63087/81360).  Thanks!