# $G=D_8$ and $H=\langle r^2 \rangle $ why is $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

In my homework I have:

$G=D_8$ (Dieder) and $H=\langle r^2 \rangle$

It it said is that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Why is that? Why not $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $G/N=\{[1],[r],[\sigma ],[r\sigma ]\}$ and as you see, there are no element of order 4.

Comment: Typo, have corrected now, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Calculate $G/H$:
Clearly, $$G/H=\{g o H|g \in G \}$$
So, $$G/H=\{1 o <r^2>,r o <r^2>,s o <r^2>,rs o <r^2>\}$$
where $s$ is reflection and $r$ is rotation and $o$ is composition operation of $G$.
Clearly $G/H$ is not cyclic as it does not have any generator but $\mathbb{Z_4}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Why do you have addition between $r+r^2$,shouldn't it be multiplication?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think it's fine now!

Comment: I still don't see why it is addition. Both G and H are multiplicative groups. Do you mean the composition "$\cdot$" instead of addition "+"?

Comment: Yes I have written composition now. Thanks.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is clear or more thing I have to add on?

Answer (score 2):

Since $Z(D_8)$ is generated by $r^2$ we have $G/H=D_8/Z(D_8)$. If it would be cyclic then $D_8$ would be abelian, a contradiction. Hence $D_8/Z(D_8)$ must be isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

Reference: [If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian)