# A proof of Sylow III for $|G|=pq$, with $p,q$ distinct primes, $p<q$. (Solution verification).

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is a [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification) question.

As a lemma, a group $G$ as in the title is centerless or Abelian. For a proof, see @NickyHekster's answer below or the link in the comments. So, as for the main focus in the title (determining $n_p$ and $n_q$ for such $G$'s), we have to address the following two cases:

- **Case "$G$ centerless"**. If $Z(G)$ is trivial, then every nontrivial element of $G$ has centralizer of order $p$ or $q$. Therefore, the Class Equation yields:
  $$pq=1+k_pp+k_qq \tag 1$$
  where $k_i$ is the number of conjugacy classes of size $i=p,q$. Since $\langle x\rangle=C_G(x)$ for every $x\in G\setminus\{e\}$, there are exactly $k_qq$ elements of order $p$ (they are the ones in the conjugacy classes of size $q$); but each subgroup of order $p$ contributes $p-1$ elements of order $p$, and two subgroups of order $p$ intersect trivially, then $k_qq=m(p-1)$ for some positive integer $m$ such that $q\mid m$ (because $q\nmid p-1$).
  Therefore, $(1)$ yields:
  $$pq=1+k_pp+m'q(p-1) \tag 2$$
  for some positive integer $m'$; but then $q\mid 1+k_pp$, namely $1+k_pp=nq$ for some positive integer $n$, which replaced in $(2)$ yields:
  $$p=n+m'(p-1) \tag 3$$
  In order for $m'$ to be a positive integer, it must be $n=1$ (which in turn implies $m'=1$, and finally $k_q=p-1$). Therefore:
  $$1+k_pp=q \tag4 $$
  Now we have two options: if $p\nmid q-1$, then $(4)$ is false, and hence $G$ can't be centerless (so, it is Abelian, see Case "$G$ Abelian"); on the other hand, if $p\mid q-1$, then by $(4)$ there are exactly $q-1$ elements of order $q$ (namely $\bf{n_q=1}$) and hence $q(p-1)$ elements of order $p$ (namely $\bf{n_p=q}$).
- **Case "$G$ Abelian"**. Suppose there are two distinct cyclic subgroups of order $p$, say $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$; then, $\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^2$: contradiction, because $p^2\nmid pq$. So, there is at most one cyclic subgroup of order $p$, namely $n_p\le 1$. By the same argument, there is at most one cyclic subgroup of order $q$ (because $q^2\nmid pq$), namely $n_q\le 1$. Therefore, there are at least $pq-1-(p-1)-(q-1)=$ $(p-1)(q-1)\ge 2$ elements of order $pq$, and for any $x$ of them, $x^q$ has order $p$ and $x^p$ has order $q$, and hence $\bf{n_p=1}$ and $\bf{n_q=1}$. $\space\Box$

Comment: The "shortcut lemma" Nicky is mentioning  is also very popular - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian) for example.

Comment: Yes indeed, @DietrichBurde, thanks. Though, the lemma rightly shortcutted as you and Nicky pointed out is just ancillary to the main result of finding $n_p$ and $n_q$ in the only two possible cases ($G$ centerless and $G$ Abelian, indeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shortcut the proof by using the fact that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. This is not hard to prove.

Now, if $G$ is *not* abelian, then $Z(G) \lt G$. If $|Z(G)|=p$ or $=q$, then by the opening remark, $G$ would be abelian. The only possibility left is $Z(G)=1$, that is $G$ is centerless.