# Сyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Group $G$ is abelian and finite. $\langle g\rangle = G$. $p$ is order of $G$ (and $\langle g\rangle$). $p=mn$, $m > 1$, $n > 1$. Why $\langle g^m\rangle < G$ (not $\langle g^m\rangle \le G$)?

Comment: You are using $p$ for a composite number!

Comment: $\left<g^m\right>=G$ iff $m=1$.

Comment: $g^p=(g^m)^n=e$, so $\lvert\langle g^m\rangle\rvert\le n<mn=p=\lvert G\rvert $

Comment: Note that “$\langle g^m\rangle\lt G$” **implies** $\langle g^m\rangle \leq G$. They are both correct statements. It’s just that the former is stronger than the latter because it says more.

Comment: if $G=\langle g\rangle$ then group $G$ is cyclic so certainly [abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44995/are-cyclic-groups-always-abelian)

Answer (score 2):

Basic result in theory of cyclic groups:   $\langle g\rangle =G\implies |g^m|=\dfrac n{\operatorname {gcd}(n,m)}$, where $n=|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

As $|\langle g^m \rangle | = \dfrac {|G|} m$ and $m > 1$, so $|\langle g^m \rangle |  <  |G|$.